# Issue with testing callback of continuation - no method on provided controller type

Tags: apex, code-coverage, continuation

I have an apex class that is using a [chained continuation concept](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/limitless-chaining-of-continuation-object-in-salesforce/#more-6101).

My class functions fine and appears to be making all of the callouts as expected. Now I am trying to write my test class for code coverage and I am running into some issues. The problem I am facing is with invoking the callback. When trying to do so, I get an error `No method 'callback1Response()' on provided controller type.`

Here is some minimal code to show my setup:

**Class**

```
global with sharing class MyController {

    // Continuation URL
    private static final String CALLOUT_URL = 'callout:Profile/';

    /**
     * Create continuation callout
     */
    @RemoteAction
    public static Object createContinuation(String dataSource, String params) {
        return constructCallout('callback1Response', dataSource, params);
    }

    /**
     * Construct the continuation callout
     */
    private static Object constructCallout(String callbackMethodName, String dataSource, String params) {

        // Get URI
        String uri = generateCalloutURI(dataSource, params);

        // Begin continuation
        Continuation chainedContinuation = new Continuation(120);
        chainedContinuation.continuationMethod = callbackMethodName;

        // HTTP Request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(CALLOUT_URL + uri);
        chainedContinuation.state = chainedContinuation.addHttpRequest(req);
        return chainedContinuation;
    }

    /**
     * Create create the callback response from the continuation
     */
    public static Object callback1Response(Object state) {
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse((String) state);
        return response.getBody();
    }

     /**
     * Generate URI for API Callout
     */
    public static String generateCalloutURI(string dataSource, string params) {
        // Vars
        String URI = '';

        // Switch based on provided method
        switch on dataSource {
            when 'getCommentsOuter' {
                URI ='ABC123';
            }
            when else {
                // default
            }
        }
        return URI;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
    private static void testContinuation() {
        Continuation con = (Continuation) MyController.createContinuation(
            'getCommentsOuter',
            '{"EMPLID": "1234"}'
        );

        // Verify that the continuation has the proper requests
        Map<String, HttpRequest> requests = con.getRequests();
        system.assert(requests.size() == 1);
        system.assert(requests.get('Continuation-1') != null);

        // Perform mock callout
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setBody('Mock response body');

        // Set the fake response for the continuation
        Test.setContinuationResponse('Continuation-1', response);

        // Invoke callback method
        Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(new MyController(), con);

        // result is the return value of the callback
        System.assertEquals('Mock response body', result);
    }
```

The error seems to occur when I try and run `Test.invokeContinuationMethod`. I have come across several examples of test classes for these continuations, but all of them seem to be in a single context where it uses a unique label per continuation which isn't quite the same setup I am following.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this test using this chained concept?

Comment: have you checked this article https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/05/apex-continuations-implementation-and-testing-in-aura-lwc.html?

It seems that you need to call `continuationCallback` in tests instead of `invokeContinuationMethod`. Because `invokeContinuationMethod` is used for actually creating invokable method inside test class

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you even wanna use continuation? isnt that depricated feature

`Every org has a limit on long-running requests that run for more than 5 seconds (total execution time). HTTP callout processing time is not included when calculating this limit. We pause the timer for the callout and resume it when the callout completes. See Execution Governors and Limits for Lightning Platform Apex limits.`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm

Comment: This was the main feature of winter 20. i feel sf hasn't updated their continuation documentation.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_apex_request_limit.htm

Answer (score 0):

`Test.invokeContinuationMethod` looks for a callback method with the signature

```
public Object callback1Response( )
```

that does not exist in your controller.

As you are using `@RemoteAction` addnotation and [your callback must be](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_process.htm) `public static` I would use a static Object variable in your controller and set it with a state object it in your `constructCallout` method.

```
state = chainedContinuation.addHttpRequest(req);
chainedContinuation.state = state;
```

After that I would invoke callback method in the test method instead of `Test.invokeContinuationMethod` invocation.

```
String result = (String) MyController.callback1Response( MyController.state );
```